# How can I modify the side menu in pinax templates?

Tags: django, pinax

I am developing a django-application on the top of pinax. I want to modify the side menu which appears after the user is logged in and has options 'account', 'password settings' and 'delete account'. I want to add more options according to my application. I just can't seem to find its templates. I have searched everywhere in my project folder. I know it is downloaded because I have all those functions available but WHERE ARE THE FILES? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean the sidebar seen in the account/settings/ url, then you'll need to modify the original file, or clone a copy of it in your project and override it from there.

[image: Pinax Template Sidebar]

The name of the file is "base.html".

Here's a snippet of code from mine:

```
    {% block subnav %}
<nav class="settings-nav">
    <div class="heading">Settings</div>
    <a class="account-settings" href="{% url "account_settings" %}">
        {% trans "Account" %}
    </a>
    <a class="account-password" href="{% url "account_password" %}">
        {% trans "Change password" %}
    </a>
    <a class="account-delete" href="{% url "account_delete" %}">
        {% trans "Delete account" %}
    </a>
```

As for where you find it, there's a few different places to look, depending on how you installed pinax.

1) Outside of a virtual environment, you'll find it at /lib/python3.6/site-packages/pinax/templates/templates/account/base.html

2) Inside of a virtual environment (like using *pipenv*), you'll have to find it from within the /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/... subtree.

Issue a `find /home/myuser -name base.html` to locate the file with the same subtree as found in the first step.

One thing I will mention is that you should not modify that specific file, only template it into your project and override it.  In this way, if your code ever moves to another machine your changes will be lost.

Copy that base.html file to myproject/templates/account/base.html and modify it there.

Hope that helps!